# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am making this Flask application. It's basically a recommendation system. Question to the main point, I have an images folder (containing my images) and an uploads folder(contains images uploaded be user). The code is generating the correct set of recommendation image paths but I am not able to show it using result.html.

error occurs here:
return render_template('result.html', image_base64=image_base64, image_paths=image_paths)

[Function Prints correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL6gz.jpg)

[Jinja error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTMIK.jpg)

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Recommendation Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Recommendation Results</h1>
    <h2>Uploaded Image:</h2>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ image_base64 }}" alt="Uploaded Image">
    <h2>Recommended Images:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for image_path in image_paths %}
           <li><img src="{{ (url_for('uploaded_file', filename=image_path)) }}" alt="Recommended     Image"></li>
{% endfor %}
    </ul>`
</body>
</html>`
```

```
@app.route('/recommend', methods=['POST'])
def recommend():
    image_filename = request.form.get('image_filename')  # Get the image filename from the hidden input
    print("Image filename:", image_filename)  #print the filename
    # Now we have the image filename and can construct the image path
    image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], image_filename)
    
    # Perform recommendations
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
        image_data = f.read()
        recommendations, image_paths = get_recommendations(image_data)  # Updated line
        
    
    # Convert image data to base64 for displaying in HTML
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')

    return render_template('result.html', image_base64=image_base64, image_paths=image_paths)#error
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related but you have extraneous parenthesis here: `{{ (url_for('uploaded_file', filename=image_path)) }}`, which should be `{{ url_for('uploaded_file', filename=image_path) }}` instead.